# Looping if condition using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, indentationerror

I'm working with Arcgis 10.1, i'm trying to loop if condition on Python code, but they give me as error :

> Parsing error IndentationError: unexpected indent (line 18)

I don't know what is going wrong.

This is the code.

```
import arcpy
import math
arcpy.AddField_management("Parcelles_class_FeatureToPoi3","new_field","DOUBLE")
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Parcelles_class_FeatureToPoi3") 
    for row in cur:
...     PointX = row.getValue("POINT_X")
...     print PointX
...     PointY = row.getValue("POINT_Y")
...     print PointY
...     EndX = row.getValue("end_x")
...     print EndX
...     EndY = row.getValue("end_y")
...     print EndY
...     dx = EndX - PointX 
...     dy = EndY - PointY 
...     azimuth = math.atan2(dy, dx)
...     print azimuth
...     azimuth_gr = azimuth*200/3.14519
...     print azimuth_gr

    if (dy>=0 and dx>= 0 ):
...     azimuth_fi = azimuth_gr
...     else : 
...         if (dy>=0 and dx<= 0 ):
...             azimuth_fi = 200- azimuth_gr
...             else :
...                 if (dy<=0 and dx<= 0 ):
...                     azimuth_fi = 200 + azimuth_gr
...                     else :
...                         if (dy<=0 and dx>= 0 ):
...                             azimuth_fi = 400 - azimuth_gr
...                             print azimuth_fi

    row.setValue("new_field", azimuth_fi)
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your else: and the lines in that code block need to be dedented one level to line up with the preceding if:. However, it is hard to be certain with those three dots at the beginning of many lines which I think are an artefact of a copy/ paste from ArcMap's Python window.

Comment: Is there an other way to compile this code on arcgis without using Python window ?!

Comment: I use IDLE which is installed with ArcGIS for Desktop for most of my Python work but I use the Python window for quick tests.

Comment: PolyGeo is correct, all the else conditions needs to line up with their respective if conditions. And I'd also recommend IDLE for coding, with a quick copy-paste into the Python window to execute.

Comment: You'll find IDLE on the Windows Start Menu under ArcGIS and then Python2.7

Comment: Comments are not suitable for long error messages and in any event I think you may be better to post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much clearer with elif then with else: if: . Not that you could also group your condiftion with hierachical if  (first test dy, then test dx =>you make 2 tests instead of up to 4 tests)

```
...     print azimuth_gr

        if (dy>=0 and dx>= 0 ):  #if should be aligned with print
            azimuth_fi = azimuth_gr
        elif (dy>=0 and dx<= 0 ):
            azimuth_fi = 200- azimuth_gr
        elif (dy<=0 and dx<= 0 ):
            azimuth_fi = 200 + azimuth_gr
        else:
            azimuth_fi = 400 - azimuth_gr
        print azimuth_fi

        row.setValue("new_field", azimuth_fi) #these line should also be aligned, otherwise you only update the last row
        cur.updateRow(row)
    del(row, cur)
```